# Dataframe to automatically create Impala table when writing to Impala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, impala

I would like to know if there is any feature of Spark Dataframe saving, that when it writes data to an Impala table, it also creates that table when this table was not previously created in Impala.

For example, the code:

```
myDataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(jdbcURL, "books", connectionProperties)
```

should create the table if it doesn't exists.

The table schema should be determined from the dataframe schema.

I look forward for your suggestions/ideas.

Regards,
 Florin

Comment: may be an idea to follow the protocol of SO and look

Answer (score 0):

I created in the past the table via a mutateStatement.execute with the relevant DDL. I checked with SPARK 2.x and append creates its autiomatically as well. Sp append is all you need.

For JDBC:

```
jdbcDF.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, table, prop)
```

For Hive via SPARK 2.x auto hive context:

```
x.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("a_hive_table_xx")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val jdbcURL = s"jdbc:impala://192.168.10.555:21050;AuthMech=0"
val connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties()
sqlContext.sql("select * from temp_table").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcURL, "users", connectionProperties)
```

Or

```
df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url="jdbc:impala://192.168.10.555:21050/test;auth=noSasl",table="tempTable", pro)
df.write.mode("overwrite").jdbc(url="jdbc:impala://192.168.10.555:21050/test;auth=noSasl",table="tempTable", pro)
```

Pass Driver jar with command

> spark-shell --driver-class-path

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The tables "users" and "tempTables" were previously created in Impala? Or they were created instantly by the Spark? What version of Spark and Impala you ere testing on?

Comment: I would like to know that as well as I believe my answer is correct. If not, then I will eat my hat.

Comment: May be I will have to